# Creating a git repo on my server

Tags: git

I logged into my server, and created a git repo:

(reference: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git)

So I created a folder:

```
blah.git
```

I then did:

```
git --bare init
```

I then went into the hooks folder and changed the permissions on the post-update.

Now locally on windows, I tried this:

git clone http://git.example.com/blah.git

and got this message:

initialized empty git in e:/gitTest/blah/.git/ fatal: http://git.example.com/blah.git/info/refs not found, did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Well I did run that command on the server.
And it seems the file info/refs does exist, but doing a cat on it shows that it is empty.

am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3):

There are no commits and, hence, no refs on your sever's repository.  So, there's nothing to clone.

Comment: Indeed, as far as I know, git will not clone an empty repository.

Comment: If you are using a 1.7.x or possibly 1.6.x version of git it will clone an empty repository over ssh. I don't know about over HTTP but I get the feeling if it does it would only be over smart-HTTP and not dumb-HTTP. (smart-HTTP uses a cgi script, dumb-HTTP uses git update-server-info)

Answer (score 1):

Sanity check: I assume the hostname in your clone URL is not literally git.example.com.

Is the protocol HTTP or HTTPS? If the latter and you're using a self-signed certificate, you'll need to disable SSL verification with the `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` environment variable for the clone. After that, set `http.sslVerify` to false with `git config`.

Do you need to provide authentication credentials to the web server?

Git over HTTP is a painful way to do it: it's s-l-o-w, and the error messages tend to be unhelpful even to the experienced. For an example of the latter, the error you're seeing about a missing `info/refs` could be an authentication problem.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution for this problem is the SCM-Manager. 
Have a look at https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager